# larvae in my balcony

Tags: species-identification, entomology

yesterday I found lots of larvae on my balcony floor.  I couldn't find out where they came from. I put some in a jar to search for them and today they started turning into pupae.
Can anyone tell me what the insect is and how to get rid of it? [image: larvae and pupa]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take a [tour] and visit the [help] for details on how to ask a good question. For identification questions we also need a location (to local area, don't need your street address), what's in the environment (e.g. nearby plants, animals etc) and preferably size or some sort of scale to refer to. As another point you are asking for an identification of a pupa - this is entomology (insects etc), not botany.

Comment: keep the pupae in a jar so we can identify the adult later

Comment: Oh, I know those things.  I've seen the empty pupa cases, and I've seen the larvae.  I did not know the pupa cases were from those particular larvae, so you've already found uot more than I knew!